# Thumb rating for wordpress - top user

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugins, rating

I am currently using gd star rating (thumb rating) to rate posts (articles - no rating on comments). What I really want to do is show a table of the top 5 users and their number of votes based on the total number of thumbs up they get for all their posts. For instance

| user | No of votes |

If this is not possible with this plugin, is there any other plugin that is capable of such. Or is there a manual way of achieving what I want. I don't mind manual coding with the right nudge.

Many thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to answer your question is to look at the database and see how the plugin is storing the "votes". I don't know that plugin, but it has to track the up/down votes somewhere, either in it's own table, or by adding a column to one of the default WP tables.

Once you track down the table that's tracking the votes, you can write a basic query that returns a limited set of users, ordered by their up/down votes. It'll look something like this:

$wpdb->get_results("SELECT id, name FROM up_down_votes_table ORDER BY what_ever_the_column is named");

The full documentation for querying the database is [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

Comment: Many thanks Emerson. The plugin has got its own table. I will try the query. Thanks again